# Проблема с mysql запросом

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE `main` SET `added`='0' WHERE `id`=(SELECT * FROM `main` WHERE `added_2`='0')
```

Нужно чтобы везде где `added_2` равен `0` чтобы `added` был тоже равен `0`

Comment: Разверните проблему пошире. Покажите структуру таблиц.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE `main` SET `added`='0' WHERE `added_2`='0'
```

Comment: у вас всяко поиск по added_2, хоть он индекс, хоть не индекс

Comment: @fonjeekay Вы сначала проверьте, а потом говорите, что не будет работать. Ибо так оно просто обязано работать. Поиск в таблицах никак не зависит от primary key. primary отвечает только за уникальность id и возможность строить фореджены на него. И за счет того, что primary реализуется индексом - он ускоряет выборку по этому полю. Но т.к. у вас все равно идет подборка по added_2, то индекс использоваться не будет (если вы его конечно отдельно по этому полю не построите)

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE `main` SET `added`='0' WHERE `id` in (SELECT id FROM `main` WHERE `added_2`='0')
```